# How do I allocate members to team without repetition?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to allocate team members to specific number number of team but with no repetition of members in any team. How do I remove Repetition?

Hi can you help me with this code, I have to allocate team members to each team. The coach can enter number of candidates, number of teams, and also name of candidates. I am able to enter the following details using Linked list and also able to generate random index for the same. 
I am creating a 2-D array to store respective number of teams and the members in it. But I am unable to make sure that every time index is unique of the list i.e. **there is no Ambiguity.**

### Here is the code

// I am accepting number of candidates and storing it in a linked list
//accept number of team
/creating 2d array to store memeber for each team  //tn - team //mem - member in each team

```java
        System.out.println("how many teams do you want: ");
        tn=sc.nextInt();
        mem=num/tn;
                String arr[][]= new String[tn][mem];
        //shuffling the list
        Collections.shuffle(name);
        for(i=0;i<tn;i++)
        {

            for(j=0;j<mem;j++)
            {
                //calculating random index
                index=random.nextInt(num);
//storing element of list in 2d array.

            arr[i][j]=name.get(index);

            name.remove(index);//removing the index
            }
            //name.remove(index);
        }
```

> random index is getting repeated if there are 4 candidates named as  [ritu, vishal, mohit, harsh]
>
> > 2 teams then the original result is team 1 [ritu, harsh] team 2 [harsh,mohit]

---

> but expected output is team 1[harsh, ritu] team 2 [vishal, ritu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you pick members at random from your pool of players. But the picked players remain in the pool.

solution : remove picked players from the pool.

Or

as you already shuffle the pool of players : just assign them in order to each subsequent team.

Comment: hi thanks, but Can you write a specific code for this I really tried but cannot get the right way.

Comment: I am using remove() but then it gives index out of bound error. Cannot understand why?

Comment: As you remove from the pool of players, the range of indexes shrinks too. You've likely forgotten to account for this when determining the next random index. You'll probably need `index=random.nextInt(name.size());`

Answer (score 0):

I use LinkedList and it's method poll(), which

> Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("how many teams do you want: ");
LinkedList<String> name = new LinkedList<>(List.of("ritu", "vishal", "mohit", "harsh"));
int tn = sc.nextInt();
int mem = name.size() / tn;
String[][] arr = new String[tn][mem];
Collections.shuffle(name);
for (int i = 0; i < tn; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mem; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = name.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: @KhushiAgarwal from my answer: "Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list".